# What is event.preventDefault preventing despite the event?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

One goal of my main controller is to prevent users from going to urls of other users. That works perfectly fine with listening on $locationChangeStart and using its events preventDefault method. Unfortunately calling this method has the strange side effect of somehow "interrupting" the work of the function "handleNotification" which has the goal of notifying the user for 2 seconds that she or he has done something illegitimate. If I comment out event.preventDefault(), everything works as expected. So my question is:  What is the 'scope' of the 'default' preventDefault prevents that I don't have on my mind and which keeps the handleNotification function from working properly?

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    ifUserIs('loggedIn', function() {
        if (newUrl.split('#/users/')[1] !== $scope.user.userId) {
            handleNotification('alert', 'You are not allowed to go here.');
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function handleNotification (type, message) {

$scope.notice = {
    content: message,
    type: type
};

$timeout(function() {
    delete $scope.notice;
    return true;
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update below**

Ok. The problem is somewhere else. In the related [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vTmV/1) everything works fine. After finding the source which is responsible for this strange behaviour I will let you know.

```
<html ng-app="mapApp">
    <div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
        <global-error message="{{notice.content}}"></global-error>
    </div>

</html>
```

And the code.

```
var mapApp = {};
mapApp = angular.module('mapApp', []);
mapApp.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $timeout) {
    $location.path('users/2')

$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, newUrl, oldUrl) {

    handleNotification('alert', 'You are not allowed to go here.');
    event.preventDefault();

});

function handleNotification(type, message) {
    $scope.notice = {
        content: message,
        type: type
    };

    $timeout(function () {
        delete $scope.notice;
        console.log('deleted');
        return true;
    }, 2000);

   $scope.$digest();

}
```

});

```
mapApp.directive('globalError', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            message: '@',
            type: '@'
        },
        template: "<div class=\"alert-box {{type}}\">\
                <p>\
                    {{message}}\
                </p>\
            </div>"
    };
});
```

**Update**
Ok. One step further. And the problem is still there. Right now I know that changing the path in the browser is something different than changing the url by putting `$location.path('users/2')` inside the code (see above). While `$location.path('users/2')` works as expected, changing the path in the browsers address bar manually just makes the address jump back to the old address without displaying the notice. So `event.preventDefault()` works correctly but  `handleNotification('alert', 'You are not allowed to go here.')` isn't. Strange.

**Update 2**
Adding `$scope.$digest()` to the end of the `handleNotification` function did the trick.